# Implementing Numpy array addition with broadcasting in C

Tags: python, c, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement Numpy array addition with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in C. The below code works for arrays with same shape, how do i make it support broadcasting?

I'll read the data for inputs from files via load_data().

> ```
> typedef struct tensor {
>   int *data;
>   int shape[4];
> } Tensor;
> int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
>   Tensor input_1, input_2, output;
>   input_1.data = malloc(256 * sizeof(int));
>   load_data("input_1", input_1.data);
>   input_1.shape[0] = 1;
>   input_1.shape[1] = 16;
>   input_1.shape[2] = 4;
>   input_1.shape[3] = 4;
>   input_2.data = malloc(256 * sizeof(int));
>   load_data("input_2", input_2.data);
>   input_2.shape[0] = 1;
>   input_2.shape[1] = 16;
>   input_2.shape[2] = 1;
>   input_2.shape[3] = 1;
>   output.data = malloc(256 * sizeof(int));
>   output.shape[0] = 1;
>   output.shape[1] = 16;
>   output.shape[2] = 4;
>   output.shape[3] = 4;
>   int total_elements =
>       output.shape[0] * output.shape[1] * output.shape[2] * output.shape[3];
>   // works when shapes are same for both inputs
>         for (int x = 0; x < output.shape[0]; x++) {
>     for (int y = 0; y < output.shape[1]; y++) {
>       for (int z = 0; z < output.shape[2]; z++) {
>         for (int w = 0; w < output.shape[3]; w++) {
>           int index =
>               x * (output.shape[0] * output.shape[1] * output.shape[2]) +
>               y * (output.shape[0] * output.shape[1]) + z * (output.shape[2]) +
>               w;
>           *(output.data + index) =
>               *(input_1.data + index) + *(input_2.data + index);
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: So, what you are trying to do, is not to use the NumPy library from C, but implement the same functionality in C yourself? In that case you have to handle the broadcast logic yourself. You need to check the dimensions and decide how/if broadcast is to be done. After that you should probably define a temporary object and copy the array that needs shape changes to there and then copy the elements as appropriate.

Comment: yes, you're right. I'm precisely looking for the broadcast algorithm.Pardon me if this is not 
 the right way to ask.